# How to save PhoneGap App

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, save, local-storage

currently I am developing an app using PhoneGap and JQueryMobile. By now, the functionality is pretty simple: All the user can do, is to create some buttons and dynamically add them to the screen.

What I want to do now, is to make this list of buttons storable. On local storage, file system... I don't know.

When the user exits the app, and then late returns, he should be able to load and extend the list he created before.

Is there any way to do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Yes. But I think it is too much to post here. It's more about the general question, if it is possible to save. In my example buttons are created dynamically. Each creation of a button changes the DOM. Maybe this DOM should be saved?

Comment: Saving the dom is generally a bad idea with JQM because not all the widgets support refresh functionality (eg: navbar).  In the case of button you do so you can store the html, insert it and then call the refresh method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some HTML markup like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="buttons">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could create a button and use local storage to save it like this:

```
var myButton1 = "<button>My Button</button>";
window.localStorage.setItem("button1", myButton1);
```

And then retrieve it and display it on the page like this:

```
var myButton1 = window.localStorage.getItem("button1");
$("#buttons").html(myButton1);
```

For multiple buttons, you could store them as an array:

```
var myButtons = [
    "<button>My Button 1</button>",
    "<button>My Button 2</button>
];
window.localStorage.setItem("buttons", myButtons);
```

And then retrieve it and display them on the page:

```
var myButtons = window.localStorage.getItem("buttons");
var buttons = "";
foreach (var button in myButtons) {
    buttons += button + "<br/>";
}
$("#buttons").html(buttons);
```